# How to use jsTree events with AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, jstree

I load my tree successfully using a directive in `AngularJS`.Now i want to add events (here select node) in my tree, so i did like this. but i can't see my alert .

My code:

```
app.directive('jstree', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
     scope: {
          jstree: '='
         }, 

link: function(scope, element, attrs) 
      {        
       scope.$watch('jstree', function() 
         {

           $(element).jstree({

                          "json_data" :{
                            "data":scope.jstree.data
                            },

                           "themes" : {
                                     "theme" : "classic",
                                      "dots" : true,
                                     "icons" : true
                                    },
                            "plugins" : [ "themes", "json_data" ]
                        }, false); 
            }, true);

            // select a node
            element.bind("select_node.jstree",function(e, data) {
     $window.alert(e.data);

                        });

             }
          };
});
```

Any idea  were i went wrong ?

Comment: Can you try to store the reference of `$(element).jstree({...})` in a variable such as `tree` and then do `tree.bind`

Comment: @Chandermani, i try it, but i still have no result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use events in jstree, you have to add  "ui" in this line :

```
"plugins" : [ "themes", "json_data", "ui" ]
```

Now it works.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the jstree demo, you'll want to call bind on the jstree object, not on the element (you'll be able to bind to `click` on the element, but this probably isn't what you want)

```
$(element)
  .jstree({
    "json_data" : {
        "data" : scope.jstree.data
    },
    "themes" : {
        "theme" : "classic",
        "dots" : true,
        "icons" : true
    },
    "plugins" : ["themes", "json_data"]
  }, false)
  .bind('select_node.jstree', function(ev,data) {
    console.log('clicked');
  });
```

Comment: hi @leon, i did that, and no result, in my console, i can't see the word clicked . thks